# Google+ signout without dialog popup

Tags: google-plus, single-sign-on

I have a signout button on my page that I'm initiating this way:

```
$('#logout').click(function() {
    gapi.auth.signIn({
        'callback': function(authResult) {
            if (authResult['status']['signed_in']) {
                gapi.auth.signOut();
            } else {
                // second pass, signout succesful
            }
        }
    })
});
```

This ends up making two calls out to Google (first to validate that user is already logged in, second to sign out), thus the two passes through the callback code. This also causes the Google+ login window to briefly popup.

Is there a way to just call gapi.auth.signOut() directly without the signIn step? I have the user's Google+ id (and also access_token), if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to call the gapi.auth.signIn() every time you want to sign out. just call the gapi.auth.signOut() from anywhere to initiate the sign-out process from your app (but still signed in to Google in other tabs, which is good practice).

Example would be to just attach the gapi.auth.signOut() event to an onclick event on a button;

```
<button onclick="gapi.auth.signOut();">Sign out</button>
```